# PHP crop and resize image on the fly

Tags: php, html, css

I have a web page that displays images that I don't know their size in advance. I was trying to use the GD functions to make the script resize and crop the images from me " Just before they are displayed.. I don't need caches" but I failed.
I need a script that I can call like this

```
<img src="display.php?src=blablabla&height=100&width=200" ?>
```

or even by calculating the width and height of css to preserve the proportions and make the image touch the box from inside like

```
<img src="blabla.jpg" style="height:<?php echo $height; ?>; width:<?php echo width; ?>" />
```

I don't need any sort of caching. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 7):

**[WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/)** rlz! :)

The resize's like that:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

echo WideImage::load('image.jpg')->resize(200, 100)->asString('jpg', 80);
// image.jpg resized at 200x100 with 80% of quality
```

Comment: Wow that worked !! Thanx man .. But what if I wanna crop it slightly first so that it can touch the box (200,100) from inside .. I mean I want every pic to be 200 x 100 but with minimal loss of details by cropping.

Comment: So you can do this:

echo WideImage::load('image.jpg')->resize(200, 100, 'outside')->crop->('50% - 100', '50% - 50', 200, 100)->asString('jpg', 80);

Comment: Thanks! My version for crop/resize `WideImage::load($src)->resize($w, $h, 'outside', 'any')->crop('center', 'center', $w, $h)->output('png');`

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use the first style. Because this would be happening server-side, you can't check the CSS to get the desired size.

You just need to use the GD functions to open the appropriate file, use [`imagecopyresampled()`](http://php.net/imagecopyresampled) to resize it, and then output to the buffer using [`imagejpeg`](http://php.net/imagejpeg). Don't forget to set the right headers:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```

Answer (score 1):

OR phpthumb http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/

Demo is available at: http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/demo/phpThumb.demo.demo.php

Comment: Does phpthumb support caching?

Comment: Looks like it does support caching, per its intro "Thumbnails can be cached for less server load. Mulitple sizes of any source image can be cached seperately. Thumbnails are automatically updated when (local) source image is modified."

Answer (score -2):

You are looking for **[TimThumb](http://www.darrenhoyt.com/2008/04/02/timthumb-php-script-released/)** ([Demo](http://www.darrenhoyt.com/demo/timthumb/) | [Source Code](http://timthumb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/timthumb.php)):

> Simply copy the source code into a new
>   document called ‘timthumb.php’, place
>   it in a folder on your site (ex:
>   /scripts/) and call the image like
>   this:

```
<img src="/scripts/timthumb.php?src=/images/whatever.jpg&h=150&w=150&zc=1" alt="">
```

Comment: TimThumb is my problem. I was trying to debug a code that has timthumb and it drove me crazy that i decided to write my own code !

Comment: @ta.abouzeid: TimThumb is pretty easy to understand, what are trying to do / isn't working?

Comment: Check this theme, http://www.web2feel.com/scarlett-theme/
it uses timthumb in the slide.php file and itsn't working for all the people out there